# Android JSONReader no class found

Tags: java, android

I have an error with android development. In fact i try to parse a JSON flux with stringtree library.
So i import the library in build path but i have this error when i launch my application : 
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.stringtree.json.JSONReader

Have you an idea ?

Best regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is an error with the latest `ADT tools`. You should place your jar inside a folder called `libs` not `lib` or something different.